My gift box in Once Upon a Tower doesn't fall. Does anyone know why?
My gift box in Once Upon a Tower doesn't fall. Does anyone know why?

I've tried the daily gift box, the Princess one, and the chicken one, but none of them fall. So I can't pass the 13x missions. Has this happened to anyone else? What can I do to pass the mission?
